# How Can I Write/Run Python On Galaxy Note 3? And What Is SL4A?

Tags: android, python, sl4a, qpython

For reasons not understood by most, I'm trying to write/run python code on my Galaxy Note 3. So far, I've installed the apps: "QPython", "Script Launcher", and "Droid Edit". In QPython, whenever I run a script, it takes me to a terminal looking window and just sits there. It doesn't even print "Hello World!" like it should. Occasionally, it runs for a split second and QPython just says "Script Ended". I've been advised to something called SL4A that I don't completely understand.

I've installed the .apk anyways, but when I attempt to run a program from Droid Edit in SL4A in background mode, I get a pop up saying "Unfortunately, SL4A has stopped." and if I click the run in terminal option I get a notification saying "Unable to open....". Has anybody had any luck with any of these running on a note 3? QPython and Droid Edit seem the most legitimate, but I can't get either to run this simple code. Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Scripting Layer for Android (abridged as SL4A, and previously
>   named Android Scripting Environment or ASE) is a library that allows
>   the creation and running of scripts written in various scripting
>   languages directly on Android devices.

QPython is a port to Python and let you access features of SL4A, execute python code & projects. It allows you to install other Python libraries via "pip", too.

Have you tried QPython Console and see if your code runs?
I have used QPython in my Note 2 and everything runs smoothly.

I suggest you review your apk build and see if there is any error or misconfiguration. You can see this for more details http://qpython.org/question/18/how-to-use-qpython-in-my-android-development/
If you are interested in building native android apps in Python, check out [Kivy](http://kivy.org/#home) too, it's a great framework for you to build cross-platform native apps.

I have not tried `Driod Edit` before so cannot comment.

Comment: I'm trying to build python apps for a regular computer, in QPython. That's what it's for, right? I am NOT trying to build apps for Android, coded with Python. Also, can I install other packages I have from my computer onto QPython such as: QSTK, Numpy, Pandas, etc?

Comment: you can try import libraries from qpypi. if you can access your local qpython /python/packages you can copy your package and place there for import. in theory it should work for numpy and pandas(haven't tried myself), but you need to take care of all related dependancies.
but for me qpython is more likely a tool for building sl4a android apps.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. I will try those two for starters, and then move on to QSTK and it's dependencies. Thanks again for the info. I'll report back the results.

Answer (score 0):

Run python program in android with Qpython: (Python 2.7.2)

> Create program and run it:

- Go to Editor.
- Write Your Script.
- Tap Save icon. ('4th icon' at bottom)
- Tap Run. ('Arrow icon' in middle at bottom)

Script will run and output/errors will be shown in logfile in notification bar.

** You can add ' #qpy:console' in starting of script . It will take you to console mode instead of logfile

> Run existing script:

- Tap on big button with python logo in center of screen.
- Tap run local script.
- Tap on script you want to run.

http://wiki.qpython.org/doc/how-to-start/

> There is another app from same developers called Qpython3 in which you can run python3 applications including scripts and projects.In Qpython3 after running script it will directly take you to console mode.